# When calling rest API with http.NewRequest, the response body is garbled

Tags: api, http, go

I try to call an API with Go. When using Postman everything is OK. But if I use the Go code from Postman the response is garbled/unclear.

Down below the code I'm using:

```
func CallAPI() {
    url := "https://url"

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer Token is normaly here")
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "Accept: application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Add("Postman-Token", "Postman token normaly here")
    req.Header.Add("Host", "host normaly here")
    req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.Add("cache-control", "no-cache")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)


    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

The response I get when I use `fmt.Println(string(body))` looks like below. I also tried other API's with this code and had the same result.

```
r�痱�
```

I also tried to unmarshal the json to a struct and did get the following error 
`Invalid character '\x1f' looking for beginning of value`

I think it's something about decoding. But I don't know what.

Comment: Please check all errors. Please check status code `res.StatusCode`. Please post what response headers you get `res.Header`.

Comment: Also consider whether you actually need all those headers. I'd be surprised if you do. If the API is any could you should only need `Accept` and `Authorization`. `User-Agent`, `Host`, `Accept-Encoding` and `Connection` should all be handled for you properly by `http.Client`.

Comment: I checked al errors, but they get passed. This is the header response `&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[application/json; charset=utf-8] Expires:[-1] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block] Date:[Tue, 29 Oct 2019 16:01:44 GMT] Cache-Control:[no-cache] X-Aspnet-Version:[4.0.30319] X-Content-Type-Options:[nosniff] Content-Length:[7106] Content-Encoding:[gzip] Connection:[keep-alive] Pragma:[no-cache]] 0xc000158040 7106 [] false false map[] 0xc0000da000 0xc0000a2370}`

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for the advice. But with or without it doesn't make any difference. As I said I think it's something with decoding because in Postman it works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask the server to send the content compressed (`req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")`), and that's what you get: a gzip response, indicated by the response header: `Content-Encoding:[gzip]`.

Remove that header (don't set `Accept-Encoding` request header), and you should get plain JSON response. Or decode the gzip response yourself.

Note that if you omit this header, the default transport will still request `gzip` encoding, but then it will also transparently decode it. Since you request it explicitly, transparent, automatic decoding does not happen. This is documented at [`Transport.DisableCompression`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) field:

```
// DisableCompression, if true, prevents the Transport from
// requesting compression with an "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
// request header when the Request contains no existing
// Accept-Encoding value. If the Transport requests gzip on
// its own and gets a gzipped response, it's transparently
// decoded in the Response.Body. However, if the user
// explicitly requested gzip it is not automatically
// uncompressed.
DisableCompression bool
```